# VSE cutting video at end

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

Any video that I have produced with my cellphone camera is trimmed at the end in VSE.

The same video is reproduced completely when I use OpenShot.

I don't think it's a bug because it happen with Blender version 2.9 and 3.0.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the VSE window with all of its settings visible when you have a video that fails added?

Comment: Thank you Marty! I figured out what was the issue: I did change the video file but rename to the previous and that cause an inconsistency with the blender's proxy cache. I deleted the proxy cache what made blender rebuild and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved deleting the proxy cache used by VSE. The issue was about cache inconsistency.